# APK won't compile after using setText in text field

Tags: android, apk, settext

Modifying an APK to try to make something slightly more user friendly. There is a login screen with username and password and a server portal field. The portal field now never needs to change. So I want to set a default text so the user does not have to type in the full portal URL

Currently looks like this

```
<EditText android:textSize="15.0dip" 
     android:textColor="@color/black" 
     android:textColorHint="@color/white" 
     android:id="@id/et_sever_url" 
     android:background="@drawable/selector_login_fields" 
     android:paddingLeft="20.0dip" 
     android:paddingRight="20.0dip" 
     android:focusable="true" 
     android:nextFocusUp="@id/et_password" 
     android:nextFocusDown="@id/bt_submit" 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="50.0dip" 
     android:layout_marginLeft="25.0dip" 
     android:layout_marginTop="20.0dip" 
     android:layout_marginRight="25.0dip" 
     android:text="@string/serverurl" 
     android:hint="@string/serverurl" 
     android:maxLines="1" android:lines="1" 
     android:layout_below="@id/et_password" 
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:inputType="textUri" 
     android:textCursorDrawable="@null" 
     android:fontFamily="sans-serif" />
```

The text and the hint just put the server url in the field but it still has to be manually typed in. I tried to use `android:setText="@string/serverurl"` but then the apk fails to compile again.

Answer (score 0):

There is no edittext properties like this : android:setText="@string/serverurl"

All you want to do set default string to your editext then in xml just use below property.

```
android:text="@string/serverurl"
```

Also remove the hint property you really don't need that because you are seting default text so hint won't be shown.

Also second why to do this in java code like below.

```
EditText edtServerUrl =findViewById(R.id.et_sever_url);
 edtServerUrl.setText(R.string.serverurl)
```

Put above code inside onCreate() method of activity.

Comment: OK what you suggest for android:text="@string/serverurl"  is what I originally had but it was an empty field with that. So for the second part what file would I inject that code into? I am doing this from a decompiled APK just trying to realistically get rid of that field altogether if I can.